# Absolute Positioning height

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have a div containing text absolutely positioned inside a relative div containing an image. I am designing a fluid layout. The idea being the title text appears on the image in a consistent position.

I have two problems. The first is if I set height 0 on the text div, it should align with the top of the image div. However, it jumps above this to the top of the doc. I cannot work out why, I though absolute divs, position to the first relative div.

The second problem is as I change the width of the image div/browser, the vertical position changes. So lets say at the browsers widest, the top of the title text starts an 8th of the way down the title image. When I reduce the browser size, the top of the title text starts to creep towards the top of the image div and can even go above it over the top menu. Both the title text and title image size based on the width so this should remain constant.

Thanks for any help.

```
HTML
<div class="header_image">
<img src="/photos/<?php echo $row1['cover']; ?>.jpg" style="width:100%;" alt="banner">

<div unselectable="on" class="header_text">
  <h1 class="voyage_to" style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em <?php echo $colour; ?>, 0 0 0.2em <?php echo $colour; ?>;">xxxxxxxx</h1>
  <h1 class="bold_title" style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em <?php echo $colour; ?>, 0 0 0.2em <?php echo $colour; ?>;"><?php echo $row1['name']; ?></h1>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.header_image{
width:100%;
position:relative;
}

.header_text {
    line-height:1;
position: absolute;

top:20%;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0 auto;

z-index: 1;

   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

}
```

Comment: Height (or, vertical positioning) in percent can be problematic. This is usually based on the height as set on the nearest parent, not on its _computed_ height. Now since the `header_image` doesn't have a height set in the css, we don't know beforehand what it is, so we can't predict the `top` of its children if the `top` is given in percent.

Comment: That said, I can't seem to duplicate the issue. Can you create a snippet that demonstrates what goes wrong?